# Ergodicity of Integrated ergodic process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, ergodic-theory, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $X_t, t\geq -1$ be an ergodic process and let $\mu$ be its invariant measure. For example, let us consider $X_t$ solution of an overdamped Langevin equation
$$
dX_t = -V'(X_t)\, dt + dW_t,
$$
where $W_t$ is a Brownian motion. If $V$ is a dissipative potential, we have that the invariant measure $\mu$ of $X_t$ has density $\rho$
$$
\rho(x)= \frac1Z \exp\left(-V(x)\right),
$$
with $Z$ the normalization constant. The latter can be derived by solving the stationary Fokker-Planck equation associated to the SDE above.

For simplicity, let $X_{-1}\sim \mu$ so that $X_t\sim \mu$ for all $t \geq -1$. Let now for $t \geq 0$
$$
Y_t=\int_{t-1}^tX_s \, ds,
$$
be a "moving average" of $X_t$.

Is there an argument why $Y_t$ is itself ergodic? What will be the relationship between the invariant measures of $X_t$ and $Y_t$?

Comment: You may want to state the mathematical property that you are given from the statement "$X_t$ is ergodic" and then also state the property you are trying to show to be able to conclude "$Y_t$ is ergodic."  It may eventually help to assume something nice about $X_s$ such as boundedness.

Comment: Remember that any integral can be approximated by step functions

Comment: @Michael I modified the question by introducing a clarifying example.

Comment: @AdriánHinojosaCalleja How would this help?

Comment: @G.Gare I'm not sure if this will help: if X is ergodic, does the step functions are ergodic? does the limit of ergodic processes is ergodic? That's the way I would try to tackle the problem.

Comment: @G.Gare : I was talking more about the definitions.  By "$X_t$ is ergodic" do you mean $\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T X_tdt = E[X_0]$ with prob 1?  Are you trying to show $\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T Y_tdt = E[Y_0]$ with probability 1?